# My users get many error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" from StoreKit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I send log from production every time a user try to subscribe to one of my auto renewable subscription and it failed.
Most of the time, it works, but for many users (maybe 20%), StoreKit returns with this failure : SKErrorDomain, code 0. And when I log the `error.description`, I get "(null)".

Here is some code I use :

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];`

And then I observe the payment queue:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                [self didStartTransactionPurchase:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self didPurchaseTransaction:transaction queue:queue];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self didFailTransaction:transaction queue:queue error:transaction.error];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self didRestoreTransaction:transaction queue:queue];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                [self didDeferTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Does any one has the same issue ? What could I do to go further ?

Comment: hello @vmeyer
did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi, not yet. Do you have the same errors ?

Comment: hi @vmeyer, any solutions on this? we have the same issue.

Comment: Sadly no ☹️ I contacted Apple, and they asked me device logs to investigate. 
But I had no logs to send because it happen only in production and I can't contact users because there are anonymized...

Comment: I'm seeing this error as well when using `SKStoreProductViewController` in MacCatalyst.